# Reminder when dotnet ef command: Cannot execute because the specified command or file cannot be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework

I use EF to migrate the database in a project based on .net core 3.0, the dos command window performs the migration and executes the migration command, and Visual Studio prompts

Could not execute because the specified command or file could not be found

I would like to state that the migration command is exact and the Entity Framework nuget package is installed

Most of the code is class, so there should be no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually because you have not installed the necessary tools, please execute the following command to install the corresponding tools:

1. `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef`

This command installs dotnet ef as a global tool. If the latest version is not used in the project, please install the corresponding version and use the following command:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version <version number>
```

If the installation is wrong, you can use the uninstall command:

```
dotnet tool uninstall --global dotnet-ef
```

2. `dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design`

Before tools can be used with a particular project, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design needs to be added to that project.